# ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment using OR

Tags: jquery, angularjs

```
data['username'] = $("#username").val() || validated = false;

if(validated){
//save to db
}
```

I want to write shorter code, to assign validated to false if username is empty. But why it doesn't work with above code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`||` binds stronger than `=` (see https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)

So you need put to parentheses around the `(valided = false)`.

Otherwise it first evaluates to e.g. `('' || undefined)` and then attempts to assign false to this expression.